# Сборка проекта NDK библиотека LAME в Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, библиотеки, android-ndk

Мне нужен AudioRecorder, записывающий в mp3. Стандартный это делает криво, поэтому решил воспользоваться библиотекой. Все библиотеки представленные на GitHub основаны на стандартном андроидовскос AudioRecorder'е и библиотеке LAME. При сборке библиотеки во всех (сам проверял) библиотеках возникают одни и те же ошибки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я не спец в C/С++ и NDK, поэтому проблему решить не могу. Пытался поиграться с include'ами, но ничего не вышло. Что делать?

Comment: По этой инструкции делали? http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/view.do;jsessionid=LPRBW9vR54pVnGnLFFVhvmXc3mBCgnyn9vdnvQ2fzWHR1tv1x0ML!413042337?v=T000000090

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте в `Application.mk` строку

> APP_CFLAGS += -DSTDC_HEADERS